# Ansible: approach to loop through a complex variable in order to access different layers under the same task

Tags: ansible

What would be the correct approach to loop through a complex dictionary variable in an Ansible play in order to be able to call items from different layers of the variable in the same module/task?

The variable in question looks like this (but it could be any number of layers down, so far I only have about 3 layers down):

```
installation:
  v10:
    installs: yes
    das_username: dasusr
    das_group: dasadm
    package_name: v10.tar.gz
    binaries_folder: binaries
    install_path: /opt/V10
    instances:
      inst1:
        enabled: yes
        username: inst1
        group: dbiadm
        port: 50000
        databases:
          jts:
            name: 'JTS'
            state: present
            pagesize: 32768
          rtc:
            name: 'CCM'
            state: absent
            pagesize: 16384
          rqm:
            name: 'QM'
            state: absent
            pagesize: 32768
      inst2:
        enabled: no
        username: inst2
        group: dbiadm
        port: 50005
        databases:
          warehouse:
            name: 'DW'
            state: present
            pagesize: 32768
  v9:
    installs: no
    instances:
      inst3:
        enabled: no
        databases:
          rqm:
            name: 'RM'
            state: absent
            pagesize: 32768
          lqe:
            name: 'LQE'
            state: absent
            pagesize: 16384
```

Tasks include creating databases using the install_path (layer 1) and databases parameters (layer 3) under the same shell module or in a template.

For example (the task should look something like this) but with the correct method of looping:

```
- name: Creating the databases
  become_user: "{{ item.0.instances.username }}"
  shell: "./db2 create database {{ item.1.name }} using pagesize {{ item.1.pagesize }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ item.0.install_path }}/bin"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ installation }}"
    - instances.databases.clm
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a trivial feat to do such thing in ansible, becase loops in ansible are one-dimensional. There is a hackish way though, you can use nested [includes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse) with [loop control](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control). So let's say i put all of your variables inside `vars.yml` and have a following files:

#### playbook-nested.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: pass version forward
      include: instances.yml v="{{ version_item }}"
      with_items: "{{ installation }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: version_item
```

#### instances.yml

```
- name: Pass instance forward
  include: databases.yml i={{ instance_item }}
  with_items: "{{ installation[v].instances }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: instance_item
```

#### databases.yml

```
- name: echo command
  debug: msg="./db2 create database {{ item.name }} using pagesize {{ item.pagesize }}"
  with_items: "{{ installation[v].instances[i].databases.clm }}"
  when:  installation[v].instances[i].databases.clm  is defined
```

So the output of command `ansible-playbook playbook-nested.yml -e @vars.yml` will be:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [pass version forward] ****************************************************
included: /home/user/instances.yml for localhost
included: /home/user/instances.yml for localhost

TASK [Pass instance forward] ***************************************************
included: /home/user/databases.yml for localhost

TASK [echo command] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'state': u'absent', u'name': u'RQM', u'pagesize': 32768}) => {
   "item": {                                                                                                                                      
       "name": "RQM",                                                                                                                             
       "pagesize": 32768,                                                                                                                         
       "state": "absent"                                                                                                                          
   },                                                                                                                                             
   "msg": "./db2 create database RQM using pagesize 32768"                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                  
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'state': u'absent', u'name': u'LQE', u'pagesize': 16384}) => {
   "item": {                                                                                                                                      
       "name": "LQE",                                                                                                                             
       "pagesize": 16384,                                                                                                                         
       "state": "absent"                                                                                                                          
   },                                                                                                                                             
   "msg": "./db2 create database LQE using pagesize 16384"                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                  

TASK [Pass instance forward] ***************************************************
included: /home/user/databases.yml for localhost
included: /home/user/databases.yml for localhost

TASK [echo command] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'state': u'present', u'name': u'JTS', u'pagesize': 32768}) => {
   "item": {                                                                                                                                      
       "name": "JTS",                                                                                                                             
       "pagesize": 32768,                                                                                                                         
       "state": "present"                                                                                                                         
   },                                                                                                                                             
   "msg": "./db2 create database JTS using pagesize 32768"                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                  
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'state': u'absent', u'name': u'CCM', u'pagesize': 16384}) => {
   "item": {                                                                                                                                      
       "name": "CCM",                                                                                                                             
       "pagesize": 16384,                                                                                                                         
       "state": "absent"                                                                                                                          
   },                                                                                                                                             
   "msg": "./db2 create database CCM using pagesize 16384"                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                  
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'state': u'absent', u'name': u'QM', u'pagesize': 32768}) => {
   "item": {                                                                                                                                      
       "name": "QM",                                                                                                                              
       "pagesize": 32768,                                                                                                                         
       "state": "absent"
   }, 
   "msg": "./db2 create database QM using pagesize 32768"
}

TASK [echo command] ************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=8    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I'm not sure what does clm mean and do i have to loop over `databases` as well, but i think the concept is clear to you now.

You can also use the nested_loops on the lower level i guess.

Comment: Andrew, thank you very much for enlightening me with this valuable information which I was unable to find anywhere else!!

I had this task:

`- name: echo command
  debug: msg="install value is {{ installation[v].installs }}, user {{ installation[v].instances[i].username }}, database {{ installation[v].instances[i].databases[d].name }}"`

and got exactly what I needed:

`[...]
TASK [test.test : echo command] ************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "./db2 create database if value is True using user inst1 and database name JTS"
}`